# Cannot add identity.basic User Token scope for Slack app

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am developing a slack app in an organisation in which I have Org Admin permission. I have been able to add other User Token Scopes such such `admin.users:read` and `admin.users:write`.

I want to add the `identity.basic` token to use the `users.identity` API method but whenever I try to add the scope and reinstall the app into my organisation, an error pops up saying:

> Invalid permissions requested. invalid_scope

How do I add the `identity.basic` user token scope?

Answer (score 1):

The `identity.basic` scope is a little special in that it can only be added to a user token when you're explicitly requesting *only* `identity.*` scopes. So if your `scope` argument arrives with `admin.users:read` or any other typical scope, the "Sign in with Slack" sequence is stopped. If you go through the sequence only with `identity.basic`, the permission will be additive to existing permissions on the user token and you'll be able to request `users.identity`.